# Add Proguard rule for Navigation component

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, proguard

I want to proguard rule for navigation component as its animation file is missing and causing the app to crash

Comment: Please post the exact error you are getting

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown animation name